# How do I show a number of form fields corresponding to a number selected?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, xhtml

In other words, let's say there is a form to ask how many brother you have, you select a number from a drop-down list. After I select a number, it shows up a number of fields corresponding to the number I have selected. How can I do this feature with Javascript?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, something like this based on **@Anurag Uniyal's** answer should work, just replace the variables with your own:

```
var total = $select.find('option').length,
    inputs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    inputs.push('<input class="myinput" type="text"/>');
}

$(inputs.join('')).hide().appendTo($form);

$select.change(function () {
    var n = $(this).val();
    $('.myinput').hide().slice(n - 1, total).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For each number in in your drop-down list create `input`s and hide them, based on which number user has selected, show that many inputs

Comment: Is it possible to include a sample code? That would be great :D

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>

   <select id="numbers" onchange="numberSelected()">
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
   </select>

   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){

       $('#numbers').change(function() {
           var selectedNum = $('#numbers').val();
           for(var i=0; i<selectedNum; i++) {
              $('#numbers').after('<input></input>');
           }           
       });

     });
   </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: yes, is it better/easier to copy paste 1000 hidden input fields? anyway this was meant to be just a basic example, not a complete solution

Comment: The point is to use the DOM only once to prevent excessive reflows on the page and keep it lean...